# Error no angular: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, self, unsafe-inline

My project in Angular 6.2.8, was going very well. However, this error started to appear on the console:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-2P8mXF+NOGY5a6oJ1jDjLINrckn9RgJYdEesn+Qf4rQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more information about packages and scripts that you are using?

Comment: @Bozhinovski - this is my package.json:  [Package.json](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOOzKCzwuO9OuLlz7Iw06c0C41gPdEVCTg4)

Comment: Can you show your index.html script tags?

Comment: @Bozhinovski - Sure [index.html](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOPos0XeZT1BX7JA8m28pBI8XvG35A5TFZ8)

Comment: In index.html try adding  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Comment: @Bozhinovski - more errors appeared now - [Image Error](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOOXaNGXi05FGKFRW4uaaAsQvOt8Y1EOFGE)

Comment: SOLUTION - My dockerfile was upgrading the helmet to 4.0.0, which is showing the problem. As a solution, I changed the dockerfile and informed the helmet and espress versions. Example: RUN cd /srv/opmet/ && npm init -y && npm install --save --no-progress express@4.17.1 helmet@3.23.3

Comment: Hey bud, sry for late replay. Im glad that you found solution

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the solution in the comments:

> SOLUTION - My dockerfile was upgrading the helmet to 4.0.0, which is
> showing the problem. As a solution, I changed the dockerfile and
> informed the helmet and espress versions. Example: RUN cd /srv/opmet/
> && npm init -y && npm install --save --no-progress express@4.17.1
> helmet@3.23.3

is not perfect. You just swipe rubbish under the carpet, but the rake is still there, and you will step on these sooner or later. And it's not helmet/express issue, it's just RTFM.

Crux of the matter is that [helmet 3 disable CSP by default, but Helmet 4 enables it by default](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/wiki/Helmet-4-upgrade-guide#there-is-now-a-default-policy) for additional security. So after migrate to helmet 4 you have CSP enabled by default.
You definitely have an inline script in the `index.html`:

```
<script>
if (global === undefined) {
var global = window;
}
</script>
```

that's why you have CSP violation in script-src.
Also you have CSP violation in the font-src directive because of:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

> 

Right solution is:

- either disable the CSP header in helmet (will works in any versions):
  `app.use(helmet({`
     `contentSecurityPolicy: false,`
  `}));`
- either to craft a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) for more security your app.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error and i fix it. Problem was in dict.
I have project folder in dict folder (dict/name-proj/) when i change in
"angular.json"
"outputPath": "dist/projectName" to "outputPath": "dist"
This solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me

```
app.use(helmet({
   contentSecurityPolicy: false,
}));
```

As well as a CSP in my index.html (from MSN docs)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';">
```